# Trying to get latitude and longitude data from button

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape the latitude and longitude data from "Show Map" button on this result page: https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/therapists/60148/374863?sid=5d01e84909804&ref=2&tr=ResultsName

Here's what I have tried so far=

```
button = soup.find('button', {"data-event-label":'Address_MapButton'})
print(button['data-map-lat'])
```

Full code:
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    from bs4.element import Tag

```
zipcode = int(input("Zipcode: "))
url = 'https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/therapists/{0}'.format(zipcode)
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}

page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
result = soup.find(class_='results-column')

addressArray = []

for tag in result:
    if isinstance(tag,Tag):
        _class = tag.get("class")

        if _class is None or _class is not None and "row" not in _class:
            continue

        link = (tag.find(class_='result-actions')).find('a',href=True)

        _href = link['href']

        address_link = requests.get(_href, headers=headers)
        soup1 = BeautifulSoup(address_link.text, 'html.parser')

        address = (soup1.find(class_='address')).find(class_="location-address-phone")
        button = soup.find('button', {"data-event-label":'Address_MapButton'})
        print(button['data-map-lat'])

print(addressArray)
```

I'm getting a None return.
I'd like to see latitude coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to extract the appropriate attributes. I use the first match on class `btn-location` to get element housing attributes.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/therapists/60148/374863?sid=5d01e84909804&ref=2&tr=ResultsName', headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
elem = soup.select_one('.btn-location[data-map-lat]')
lat = elem['data-map-lat']
lon = elem['data-map-lon']
print(lat, lon)
```

---

OP's version:

```
soup2 = bs(address_link.content, 'lxml') 
elem = soup2.select_one('.btn-location[data-map-lat]') 
lat = elem['data-map-lat'] 
lon = elem['data-map-lon'] 
latArray.append(lat)
```